# Arquivo de log Apache

Tags: apache

Instalei o *XAMPP* e gostaria de saber como eu faço para gerenciar o arquivo de log do *apache* (meu arquivo de log está com 50MB e futuramente terei problemas).

É possível delimitar um tamanho para que, depois de atingindo, o arquivo de log *"auto recicle"*?

Comment: Estou usando o Windows

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/rotatelogs.html